# Writing files to network share

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

I have a UWP app that reads images from a folder and writes text files to the same folder. The app works fine with local folders.
However, when I try to use a network share I can still read images but cannot write text file anymore. Operation:

```
File.CreateText(<path to new file in network share>)
```

results in:

> System.IO.IOException: Network access is denied.

I can access that network share with file explorer and write files directly to it using e.g. Notepad.

Comment: Are you using a UNC file path?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Azure Storage as my network drive. My path looks like this:

\\<storageaccount>.file.core.windows.net\<file-share-name>

Answer (score -1):

Store apps normally can't access arbitrary paths, however if the user gives you access to a path using `FolderPicker` - you could save access token to that path in [`FutureAccessList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions#Windows_Storage_AccessCache_StorageApplicationPermissions_FutureAccessList) and then be able to save files to that location.

That might not work for your Azure Storage case, but then I'm sure there's a REST API you could use instead.

Comment: I'm already using FolderPicker and I can read from that network share, just not write. Same mechanism works ok for read/write when working with local folders. 
The mechanism needs to work with all netwrok shares, not only Azure.

Comment: That may be, but perhaps you should not be using `File.CreateText()`, but rather use a WinRT API based on the folder you got - e.g. `StorageFolder.CreateFileAsync()`.